# Minimum of $\frac{\sqrt{a}}{1+ab+c^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{1+bc+a^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{1+ac+b^2}$

Tags: inequality

I see this question before

$a,b,c>0$ are positive number  Find the minimum of :

> $$\omega=\frac{\sqrt{a}}{1+ab+c^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{b}}{1+bc+a^{2}}+\frac{\sqrt{c}}{1+ac+b^2}$$

I don't know how I starte from but I try :

By AM-GM

$$ab+c^2≥2c\sqrt{ab}$$ and $$ac+b^2≥2b\sqrt{ac}$$

$$bc+a^2≥2a\sqrt{bc}$$

Also :

$1+ab+c^{2}≥4\sqrt{c}\sqrt[4]{ab}$ and Angelo ...

But I don't is this can be help me ??

Comment: Is there a missing condition? Else a,b,c approach 0 we get that the infimium is 0

Comment: Is this correct?$1+ab+c^{2}≥4\sqrt{c}\sqrt[4]{ab}$